# How is Asura using Rasengan?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto anime episode 468, Asura is shown to be using a Rasengan based jutsu against Indra. If I'm not wrong, the Fourth Hokage Minato invented Rasengan several years later. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's a filler episode, so any plotholes created from it can be disregarded. This question can still be answered, but I just wanted you to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not have been rasengan, but just gathering chakra and rotating it for more power. My defense of this would be Indra's using a similar jutsu to chidori in this filler arc. Both jutsus are similar to the modern day jutsus we know, but not quite the same

Comment: also, Key word is Filler. Animation studio does whatever they want in a filler arc, whether it breaks continuity or not.

Answer (score 3):

One hypothesis that can be presented is that a large no. of jutsus had been created in the past but their knowledge and techniques might have got lost with time.

Answer (score 3):

I think it was just to show how Indra and Ashura are similar to Sasuke and Naruto. Like how Indra's sharingan is the same as Sasuke's. And that Ashura inherited the Truth Seeker Orbs like how we see Naruto with them.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are different variations and people just didn't know about the original origins of the Chakra so alot of information must be stored somewhere unknown or lost in time explaining alot of the past wish it was kept to humans and the ninja world instead of aliens etc though